# Minimum number of tries to pick all machines with a probability > 0.99

Tags: probability

Suppose we have n machines with equal probability of being picked. What is the minimum number of tries such all machines have a >0.99 probability of being picked?

I could solve for the simple case of minimum number of tries such that one particular has a >0.99 probability of being picked.
If the number of tries of picking one particular machine - t
$$\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \frac{1}{n} * ({\frac{n-1}{n}})^i > 0.99$$
$$ t >= 90 $$

I have no clue on how to approach the every machine case.

Comment: Be clear on what you are asking for... each machine individually has a probability >0.99?  If so, that is no different than the problem of asking for the first machine alone to have probability >0.99 due to the symmetry of the problem.  Or, are you asking that there is a probability at least 0.99 that *all machines are picked*?  Those are two very different problems.  For the second more interesting problem, see the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) and search for coupon collector elsewhere on this site.

Comment: My bad, I mean all machines are picked.
Have updated the problem statement.